# PHP / Apache Headers issue where apache_response_headers functions returns truncated headers keys with php-7 and above

Tags: php, http-headers, php-7

I'm facing a quite weird issue where using php apache_response_headers function returns an array of headers where the keys are truncated by one character

[image]

Notes:

- I have tested with a bare test.php file with `print_r(apache_response_headers())` and got the same results
- the issue does not appear as soon as I switch to php <= 5.6
- I have tested on a few servers with the same results
- I have searched all over but no one seem to have the same issue

Is it something that someone has encountered in the past

Would there be a way to debug this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I'm seeing the same issue on Windows, IIS 7.5, PHP 7.0.27. I do not have this issue on Linux, Apache 2.4, 7.0.30.

A pseudo workaround is:

```
$headers = array() ;
foreach(headers_list() as $header) {
    $temp = explode(':',$header,2) ;
    $headers[$temp[0]] = trim($temp[1]) ;
}

echo '<pre>' ; var_dump($headers) ;
```

I'm sure there may be situations that the above hack won't give you what you want, but I am not familiar enough with Apache's headers to know.

Comment: many thanks, this sheds a little light, I'll check the Apache versions on the servers where I can see this issue